# No route matches a named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My route file is like this

```
match '^movies\?.*\&commit=Refresh$', :to =>'movies#filter', :via => :get
resources :movies 
match 'movies/sort_by/:criteria', :to => 'movies#sort_by', :as => 'sort_by'
```

where I want to match the 1st route with

> movies?utf8=✓&ratings[PG-13]=1&ratings[PG]=1&commit=Refresh

. And in the view, I define a submit_tag that will execute the 1st route:  `= submit_tag 'Refresh', filter_by_path()`. But I keep getting:

> No route matches {:controller=>"movies", :action=>"filter"}

I don't know how to solve this since I try to check my route on rubular.com and it matches the link perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using :as in the first route

```
match '^movies\?.*\&commit=Refresh$', :to =>'movies#filter', :as => 'filter_by'
```

Then in your view,

```
= submit_tag 'Refresh', filter_by_url
```

Comment: Note: In my answer I used filter_by_url, but filter_by_path would also work here. The only difference is that url is fully qualified and path is relative. Also, parentheses are implied. You can leave them off if you want.